# WEKA 3.8 won't run on Win10

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, weka, fiji, rapid-prototyping

I can run WEKA 3.6.9 on my Win10 machine, but WEKA 3.8.4 fails.  The error is ' Could not initialize the GenericPropertiesCreater. This exception was produced: java.lang.NumberFurmatException: For input string:" '

This problem also is blocking the FIJI plugin ' Trainable Weka Segmentation' within FIJI.

I've tried removing all references to WEKA and reinstalling it.  Updating Java, WEKA, and FIJI.

I do pro bono rapid prototyping in FIJI for graduate students in medical and engineering/science fields, so please feel free to ask me any questions on image processing or machine learning.

Thanks for any help
Ron DeSpain

Comment: I'm running Weka 3.9.3 on Windows 10 without any problem, although I do not have your same configuration (e.g. no FIJI). I see the current developer version is 3.9.4.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: I get the same result with 3.9.4.  Thanks for the tip.